# How to make a multiline pandas dataframe header so it's not too long

Tags: python, pandas

I'm a python/numpy/pandas newbie and am trying to put together a dataframe of stock data with some simple calculations.  I'd like the header names to be descriptive enough that they are self explanatory, like:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
vxx_data = pd.read_csv('VXX5')
vxx_data['day_range'] = vxx_data['High']-vxx_data['Low']
```

This appears as:
[image]

I'd like to format the data to include only two decimals, but my main concern is how to make the dataframe column header name multilined so that instead of 'day_range', it appears as:
 day 
 
range
...so that the column isn't so wide.

I've googled this a dozen ways and can't find anything that works.
Is this possible in pandas?

Comment: "This appears as:" where?

Comment: I'm simply executing vxx_data in Jupyter notebook, but it outputs the same way when I run the .py script anywhere

Answer (score 0):

You can limit it to two decimals using:

```
vxx_data = vxx_data.round(2)
```

I don't believe there's a way to put column headers on two lines, but you may be interested in looking into the following:

```
pd.set_option("max_colwidth", 1)
```